# Can you consult modification indices of a fixed-factor approach of longitudinal invariance to aid decision making in other scaling approaches?

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, invariance

I am learning how to test measurement invariance with different scaling approaches
and came across a book chapter that said that modification indices of a fixed-factor approach are more trustworthy than other scaling approaches.

It also mentioned that the different scaling approaches are just looking at the same data from different "windows", thus the difference in scaling approach is but shifts in perspective.

Considering the above, I was wondering if probing MI in different scaling approaches can aid finding sources of misfit in the model. I am aware that considering theory is crucial and relying on MI is not ideal. But it left me curious. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It may be useful to provide a reference to the chapter you are talking about.

Comment: Here is a very useful article to read about metric invariance using different scaling methods: https://doi.org/10.5964/meth.10177

Comment: Shawn thank you for pointing out the vagueness in how I asked my question. Terrence, thank you for the link. I read the article and it was very interesting. It gave me a different way of looking at invariance testing and more depth.